# Monsters of Encounter Levels below 1 in Legend

Tags: character-creation, monsters, encounter-design, legend

In legend, antagonists/monsters/loot-on-legs are made the exact same way as PC's, though less restricted.

I have always loved hordes in epic fantasy, but the rules make this hard to portray at lower levels, since a monster is at least Level 1, and therefore an encounter with it is at least Encounter Level 1.

How do you make an Encounter of level 1, featuring multiple enemies? The classic goblin swarm, for example. I know that I can house rule to my hearts content, obviously, but I would rather see something that is actually *playtested*, preferably also from official sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to handle it in the rules provides in the current version of the core book, but there is a pair of bonus content releases that provide just what you seem to need.

[Mooks.pdf](http://www.ruleofcool.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Mooks.pdf) provides the generic rules for mooks, which are still limited to a minimum encounter level of 1, which isn't answering your question, but it's on these rules that the official solution is based.

[Myriads.pdf](http://www.ruleofcool.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Myriads.pdf) provides the solution. Myriads can do what you want, but also have a few more uses as explained in the text. They are designed to fix the problem you're having.

Comment: The myriad rules seems interesting. I was hoping for a creature track called "horde" or something though, with rules fitting the flavor.

Comment: Myriad basically means 'many' and these rules are meant to provide a 'horde' equivalent. I haven't seen any track for a Horde, and that is a potential balance nightmare because of all the potential interactions with other tracks. I don't think there will be an official horde track, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Undreren: just a warning, as of this writing, mooks are little more than cannon fodder and have an update in the works. Including, if I remember correctly, ways to make Myriads that have a track or four. You can find info on that and other updates for "1.0" at [#legend](http://www.gamesurge.net/chat/legend/).

Answer (score 1):

Mooks are the best answer, but I will point out that it's pretty trivial to make a “level ½” character in *Legend*. At level 1, a character has HP equal to twice their class's HP/level plus twice their KDM, and has the first Circle from two of his Tracks. It would be fairly simple to halve both of these and get something roughly half as powerful. Such creatures may die too quickly to be a threat, though. Mooks are a better bet.